# How to avoid CA1051:DoNotDeclareVisibleInstanceFields in .aspx.designer.cs files?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop

Using the built in Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2010 I get CA1051 on all fields in the designer files for the aspx files.

```
Warning 111 
CA1051 : Microsoft.Design : Because field 'Product.PageTitle' is visible 
        outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility to private 
        and add a property, with the same accessibility as the field has 
        currently, to provide access to it. 
Product.aspx.designer.cs    22
```

I don't want to remove the rule for other files.
I don't want to manually edit the generated designer files.

Can I somehow avoid this message in any other way then supressing the message field by field in the error list?

Answer (score 1):

Make the Product.PageTitle private. If you want to expose it outside of the Product class then create a property for it.

Current situation:

```
public/internal string PageTitle;
```

Desired situation:

```
public/internal string PageTitle { get; set; }
```

Comment: //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.

Comment: True, but I don't want to manually edit all designer files if I don't have to. I think having the declarations in the designer file is a good thing. Adding a new partial class seems like overkill. I was hoping for some replacement rule or matching pattern that could be used to simply avoid the generated files.